# @font-face problem with chrome

Tags: css, font-face, embedded-fonts

I used the Museosans500 font with the following syntax

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MuseoSans500';
    src: url('MuseoSans_500-webfont.eot');
    src: url('MuseoSans_500-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
        url('MuseoSans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('MuseoSans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('MuseoSans_500-webfont.svg#webfontkQkWxTED') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It is working fine in Firefox, but it is not displaying the font correctly in Chrome.

Comment: This is a fontsquirrel implementation right? And define not correctly, is it not loading at all or is the font looking choppy?

Comment: The fonts are loading but it looks choppy.

Comment: You unfortuneatly can't expect that the fonts look exactly alike across all browsers, but usually fonts via FontSquirrel look fine for Chrome with me - Can you try another font and see if you still experience the samme issue?

Comment: What does it mean "it's not displaying font correctly"? Does it show another font? Is it crappy rendered or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what issues you are experiencing but this website http://seanmcb.com/typekit/webkit-antialiasing-test.html gives a great run-down of test cases of a webkit bug, which might be what you're experiencing.

I'm seeing the anti-aliasing issue in my own site and I'm going to try out the pseudo-element trick. The bug as described by the site: "In Webkit browsers on Mac, @font-face fonts render with whatever antialiasing setting the previously rendered text was using."

Next, would be good to see if webkit has a bug open for this issue.

Comment: This is now fixed in webkit (the above was marked as duplicate): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67996

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct - make sure you define SVG first, otherwise Chrome will use that to display the font, and this will look jagged. By putting it first you ensure that Chrome will use one of the later definitions to display the font.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the version of Chrome you're running on Windows. I know Chrome 10's @font-face rendering was not too smooth. Please take a screenshot and share with us and then possibly update your browser, take another screenshot and compare them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Put SVG format before all others on your CSS.